# Getting SQL exception with @oneTomany in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have 4 tables as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_EMP_P01` (
`COL_EM01_PKEM` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_DOB` date NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_EY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_GN` int(11) NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_PJT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_MN` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_NM` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_PF` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_QL` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SG` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SVF` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_UID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_FKEMAD` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SUEC` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SUPI` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SUQC` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SUSC` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM01_SUSVC` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`DATE_CREATED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`DATE_MODIFIED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`UPDT_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`COL_EM01_PKEM`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM01` (`COL_EM01_FKEMAD`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM02_1` (`COL_EM01_SUEC`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM02_2` (`COL_EM01_SUPI`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM02_3` (`COL_EM01_SUQC`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM02_4` (`COL_EM01_SUSC`),
KEY `FK_EM01_CM02_5` (`COL_EM01_SUSVC`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM01` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_FKEMAD`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P01` (`COL_CM01_PKADD`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM02_1` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_SUEC`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM02_2` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_SUPI`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM02_3` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_SUQC`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM02_4` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_SUSC`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_CM02_5` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM01_SUSVC`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`)
)  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='Employee';  


CREATE TABLE `TBL_EMP_A01` (
`COL_EM02_PKEMAU` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_EM02_SC` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_EM` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_FMC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_FN` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_IN` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
`COL_EM02_PTF` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_TCN` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_YFI` double DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_FKEMAU` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_EM02_SUIN` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_EXP` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_CTE` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_ADRC` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_ADRCN` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
`COL_EM02_IDPT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_CCEN` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_EM02_CJT` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`COL_EM02_PKEMAU`),
KEY `FK_EM01_EM02` (`COL_EM02_FKEMAU`),
KEY `FK_EM02_CM02_0` (`COL_EM02_SUIN`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM01_EM02` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM02_FKEMAU`) REFERENCES `TBL_EMP_P01` (`COL_EM01_PKEM`),  
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM02_CM02_0` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_EM02_SUIN`) REFERENCES    `TBL_COM_P02` (`COL_CM02_FBID`)
)  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='EmployeeAux';  

CREATE TABLE `TBL_COM_P07` (
`COL_CM07_PKRD` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_CM07_CRN` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`COL_CM07_CRMN` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`COL_CM07_PKRD`)  
  )  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='ReferralDetails';

 CREATE TABLE `TBL_RFR_A01` (
`COL_RF01_FKRD` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_RF01_FKEMAU` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`COL_RF01_CRSEQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`COL_RF01_FKRD` , `COL_RF01_FKEMAU`),
KEY `FK_CM07_RF01` (`COL_RF01_FKRD`),
KEY `FK_EM02_RF01` (`COL_RF01_FKEMAU`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_CM07_RF01` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_RF01_FKRD`) REFERENCES `TBL_COM_P07` (`COL_CM07_PKRD`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_EM02_RF01` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_RF01_FKEMAU`) REFERENCES `TBL_EMP_A01` (`COL_EM02_FKEMAU`)
)  CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Using hibernate code for mapping oneTomany is as:

```
@Valid
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
@OrderColumn(name = "COL_RF01_CRSEQ")
@JoinTable(
        name = "TBL_RFR_A01",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COL_RF01_FKRD")},
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COL_RF01_FKEMAU")
        )
private List<ReferralDetails> referralDetailsList = new ArrayList<ReferralDetails>(2);
```

ERROR is like :

> 31/07/2016 21:04 [WARN ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
>   31/07/2016 21:04 [ERROR] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:131 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testhubdb`.`tbl_rfr_a01`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CM07_RF01` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_RF01_FKRD`) REFERENCES `tbl_com_p07` (`COL_CM07_PKRD`))
>   31/07/2016 21:04 [INFO ] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl:193 - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>   31/07/2016 21:04 [ERROR] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl:3166 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
>   31/07/2016 21:04 [DEBUG] org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager:898 - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:164)
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:741)
>           at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:589)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)

Caused by:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testhubdb`.`tbl_rfr_a01`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CM07_RF01` FOREIGN KEY (`COL_RF01_FKRD`) REFERENCES `tbl_com_p07` (`COL_CM07_PKRD`))
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

Comment: actually we don't suggest to use one to many relation,wo are used to use many to one preserve their relation.hope that can help you

Comment: The hibernate  code you write is for the TBL_COM_P07 or for TBL_RFR_A01 , can you clear it.

Comment: it is for TBL_RFR_A01 table

Comment: May be this help @JoinColumn(name = "COL_RF01_FKRD"),
   inverseJoinColumns =
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)